# BlackBerry ButtonField not found

Tags: blackberry, button, resources

I have a Blackberry application. This application downloads then plays a video file.

I am trying to switch to a model where the video is bundled in with the application inside the res/media/ folder.

The only chane in the application was making the input stream that gets displayed on the Player come from the file in res/media/ rather than the file stored in the media storage of the device. I did not change anything else related to any View components.

But now when I try to start the application I get an error dialog that says:

"Error starting [myAppName]: Class 'net.rim.device.api.ui.component.ButtonField' not found."

Since I did not change anything related to a ButtonField why would I be getting this error now that the video is bundled in?

By adding the video file it made it so that my project had many additional files that needed to be signed. They all get signed correctly. But when the application is launching I get messages in the console that say something like

> CMM: [MyAppName] no sig from 0x33

which I did not get when the video wasn't bundled with the resources. Is this somehow related to my problems?

My application does not even get a chance to begin. I have log statements at the beginning that I never see. It fails before it even begins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are receiving indicates that your app is too large. In my experience there is a practical limit of around 5MB for an application, any more than this and you will run into these strange 'class not found' errors.

Try adding a smaller video file to see whether the problem goes away.

Answer (score 1):

CMM: [MyAppName] no sig from 0x33  means that  [MyAppName] has not been signed with a code signing key identified by 0x33.  This key is only available to applications produced by RIM, and can be ignored by your application. Dont worry about it.we see it all the time.

I suspect you are trying to test your app in the emulator. try your app in device and see what happens.

Also i dont think its a good idea bundling a video in your app as it will increase the size of the app significantly. You can download the app on startup and save it in filesystem. There is a limit of about 15 MB for  a blackberry app. check this http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Testing-and-Deployment/The-maximum-size-of-a-BlackBerry-smartphone-application/ta-p/1300209

Comment: Nope I am testing on a device. Blackberry Curve 9360 to be specific. And the total size will be less than 15. It is a fairly small video file. I am just trying to test the feasibility of bundling it in with the app because we've run into some potential troubles with having it download the video.

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed the JDE you use in this project? Newer JDEs are not compatible with previous OS. I have encountered same problem before, some UI components are not available after I changed JDE to 4.7.

Comment: I didn't change JDE. If I switch back to the the version without the video bundled then it goes away. It's is good to know that I'll need to address that before updating my JDE though.